# Maintain multi select on mouse click and perform further functionalities

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Hi I am making an application in C#.

**What I am trying to achieve**

- I select Multiple rows with *CTRL* among results in *DataGridView*
- then I right click on it and it shows options
- I Click onto *choose selected* option
- The *chosen rows* stays on the *DataGridView* and other rows are removed

**Problem where I got stuck**

- I select Multiple rows with *CTRL*
- But when I Right Click on the rows the multiple selection vanishes

Note: I am using MouseClick Event for right click on rows and generate a menu. The code of this event is given below:

```
private void SearchPanelDataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip smenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
        var htest = SearchPanelDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        SearchPanelDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        SearchPanelDataGridView.Rows[htest.RowIndex].Selected = true;

        smenu.Items.Add("Clear Record").Name = "Clear Record";
        smenu.Items.Add("Pay Amount").Name = "Pay Amount";
        smenu.Items.Add("Break Apart").Name = "Break Apart";
        smenu.Items.Add("View Details").Name = "View Details";
        smenu.Items.Add("Choose Selected").Name = "Choose Selected"; // Choose Rows Option
        smenu.Items.Add("Reset").Name = "Reset";

        int CurrentMouseOverRow = SearchPanelDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
        smenu.Show(SearchPanelDataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        smenu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(smenu_ItemClicked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to handle `MouseClick` event. Just create the `ContextmenuStrip` using designer or in load event of the form. Then assign the context menu strip to `ContextMenuStrip` property of the `DataGridView`, then handle `Click` event of the `ToolStripMenuItem` which should remove non-selected rows and use such code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => !dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Contains(x) && !x.IsNewRow)
    .ToList().ForEach(x => dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(x));
```

This way, all non-selected rows will be removed and the selection will remain untouched.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems hard to avoid this behavior entirely but you can use the below workaround and restore the selected rows after DataGridView deselects them:

```
private bool SUSPEND_EVENT_HANDLING;
private List<DataGridViewRow> dgvMyGridSelectedRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

private void dgvMyGrid_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dgvMyGridSelectedRows.Clear();

    // if the mouse is down on a selected row then remember all selected rows
    if (dgvMyGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected)
        dgvMyGridSelectedRows.AddRange(dgvMyGrid.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>);
}

private void dgvMyGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsHandleCreated || SUSPEND_EVENT_HANDLING)
        return;

    // restore the remembered rows selection
    if (dgvMyGridSelectedRows.Any())
    {
        SUSPEND_EVENT_HANDLING = true;
        dgvMyGrid.ClearSelection();
        dgvMyGridSelectedRows.ForEach(x => x.Selected = true);
        SUSPEND_EVENT_HANDLING = false;
    }
}
```

The `SUSPEND_EVENT_HANDLING` is to avoid stack overflow because you select rows inside of the `SelectionChanged` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but for now you could try this:

```
    List<int> selectedRowsIndexes = new List<int>();
    private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedRowsIndexes.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
           selectedRowsIndexes.Add(row.Index);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip smenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
            var htest = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.Rows[htest.RowIndex].Selected = true;

            smenu.Items.Add("Clear Record").Name = "Clear Record";
            smenu.Items.Add("Pay Amount").Name = "Pay Amount";
            smenu.Items.Add("Break Apart").Name = "Break Apart";
            smenu.Items.Add("View Details").Name = "View Details";
            smenu.Items.Add("Choose Selected").Name = "Choose Selected"; // Choose Rows Option
            smenu.Items.Add("Reset").Name = "Reset";

            int CurrentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            smenu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            foreach (int rowIndex in selectedRowsIndexes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = (i == rowIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For this to work, the DataGridView's SelectionMode property should be set to FullRowSelect.